# Exception on special characters on Spark Dataframe returned by DropNA

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using the na.drop in Scala to return a new dataframe with non-null and non-special characters. 
When I am doing a RDD conversion of the DataFrame, i can see only the non-null characters and special characters correctly.

But when I am doing a MAP operation on the RDD to convert to Double, I am hitting an exception that there are special characters still in the RDD and crashing.

But if do the same operation on the DataFrame with no-special characters it works fine.

Please suggest the solution for this issue

inputData.show

```
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|Sepal_Length|Sepal_Width|Petal_Length|Petal_Width|Species|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|         5.1|        3.5|         1.4|        0.2|       |
|         4.9|        3.0|         1.4|        0.2| setosa|
|            |       null|         1.3|        0.1| setosa|
|         4.6|       null|         1.5|          ?| setosa|
|            |        3.6|        null|           | setosa|
|         5.4|        3.9|         1.7|        0.4| setosa|
|         4.6|        3.4|         1.4|        0.3| setosa|
|           5|        3.4|         1.5|        0.2| setosa|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Returned new Dataframe

```
val inputData1:DataFrame = inputData.na.drop() <br/>
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|Sepal_Length|Sepal_Width|Petal_Length|Petal_Width|Species|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+
|         5.1|        3.5|         1.4|        0.2|       |
|         4.9|        3.0|         1.4|        0.2| setosa|
|         5.4|        3.9|         1.7|        0.4| setosa|
|         4.6|        3.4|         1.4|        0.3| setosa|
|           5|        3.4|         1.5|        0.2| setosa|
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------+

val rdd_fromDf =inputData1.rdd

+------------+
|Sepal_Length|
+------------+
|         5.1|
|         4.9|
|         5.4|
|         4.6|
|           5|
+------------+
```

Mapping operation to convert to RDD[Double]

```
val mapReturnRDD = rdd_fromDf.map(row => row.getDouble(0))
```

The exception stack trace is as below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double<br/>
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)<br/>
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/>
16/02/17 15:13:01 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 417.0 (TID 654)<br/>
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double<br/>
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)<br/>
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/>
16/02/17 15:13:01 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 417.0 (TID 654, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double<br/>
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at $line286.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)<br/>
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/>
<br/>
16/02/17 15:13:01 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 417.0 failed 1 times; aborting job<br/>
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 417.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 417.0 (TID 654, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double<br/>
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)<br/>
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/>
<br/>
Driver stacktrace:<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)<br/>
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)<br/>
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)<br/>
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$.pangea_DFtoRDD_LabeledPoint(<console>:264)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:121)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:126)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:128)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:130)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:132)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:134)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:136)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:138)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:140)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:142)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:144)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:146)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:148)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:150)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:152)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:154)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:156)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:158)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:160)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:162)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:164)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:166)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:168)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:170)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:172)<br/>
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:174)<br/>
        at <init>(<console>:176)<br/>
        at .<init>(<console>:180)<br/>
        at .<clinit>(<console>)<br/>
        at .<init>(<console>:7)<br/>
        at .<clinit>(<console>)<br/>
        at $print(<console>)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)<br/>
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)<br/>
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)<br/>
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)<br/>
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)<br/>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double<br/>
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$pangea_Missing$$anonfun$5.apply(<console>:260)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)<br/>
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)<br/>
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)<br/>
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)<br/>
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)<br/>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you load the data but one thing for sure there is no such thing as "special character" in Spark SQL. Since output you've provided shows both characters (like `"?"`) and empty fields (like `""` which are neither `NULL` or `NaN`) as safe a assumption is that the columns of your `DataFrame` are simply `Strings` (just check `inputData.schema` or `inputData.printSchema`).

Typed methods on `Row` like `getDouble` or `getInt` are equivalent to:

```
get(i).asInstanceOf[T]
```

where `get` is of type `Int => Any`. It means these are not type safe and don't perform any type casting. If you want to perform some type of casting you can use either data source specific option (like `inferSchema` from `spark-csv`) or simply cast columns to required types:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val exprs = Seq("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width", "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width")

exprs.foldLeft(inputData)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("double"))
```

`Column.cast` method has the same semantics as standard SQL `cast` hence is type safe (if data cannot casted to a given type it means the the result is undefined or in other words `NULL`).

Comment: Thanks @zero323.. The printschema did the trick. The special charaters added in the csv were rendering the Spark Row as String instead of Double and that was the issue. Converting the program to only read for the nul and NaN as supported by Spark SQL..